# Очистить массив или присвоить пустой? a.clear() VS a = []. Разница

Tags: python, массивы

Есть в Python'e метод `clear()`, который очищает список.

Допустим, есть у меня массив `a = [1,2,3]` мне стало нужно сделать массив пустым. На своем опыте я знаю 2 подхода к решению этой задачи

1. `a.clear()`
2. `a = []`

Или ООП'шный вариант:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [1,2,3]

    def clear1(self):
        self.a.clear()

    def clear2(self):
        self.a = []
```

**Вопрос:** какая есть разница между двумя этими подходами, и, если разница есть, что и когда будет более оптимально использовать?

Comment: 1) Будут удалены элементы из списка 2) Будет создан пустой список, а предыдущий останется жив пока сборщик мусора до него не доберется

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разница будет в том случае, если вы присваиваете этот массив другим переменным. В случае с `clear()` после очистки обеим будет присвоен тот же объект, что и до очистки:

```
a = [1,2,3]
print(id(a))    # 43108936
b = a
print(id(b))    # 43108936
print(a)        # [1, 2, 3]
print(b)        # [1, 2, 3]
a.clear()
print(id(a))    # 43108936
print(id(b))    # 43108936
print(a)        # []
print(b)        # []
print(a is b)   # True
print(b is a)   # True
```

В случае с присвоением пустого массива, во переменная `b` продолжит хранить ссылку на исходный объект:

```
a = [1,2,3]
print(id(a))    # 43108424
b = a
print(id(b))    # 43108424
print(a)        # [1, 2, 3]
print(b)        # [1, 2, 3]
a = []
print(id(a))    # 43108680
print(id(b))    # 43108424
print(a)        # []
print(b)        # [1, 2, 3]
print(a is b)   # False
print(b is a)   # False
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть еще 2 способа:

**1**:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
del x[:]
```

При присвоении пустого списка - меняется идентификатор:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
id(x)
>>> 48068488
x.clear()
id(x)
>>> 48068488
x = []
id(x)
>>> 48071904  # изменяется идентификатор
```